# Виртуальная память против физической памяти

Tags: память

Может кто-нибудь объяснить разницу между виртуальной памятью и физической памятью?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Физическая память - это память, реально находящаяся в оперативном запоминающем устройстве компьютера. В ней размещаются код и данные всех запущенных на выполнение процессов. У физической памяти есть определённые недостатки:

- При запуске программы нужно гарантировать, что адреса, в которые она загружается, не заняты другими процессами
- Программа не может занимать физической памяти больше размера физической памяти
- Нужно защищать участки памяти,занятые процессом, от несанкционированного доступа других процессов

Для решения этих проблем существует аппарат виртуальной памяти. Каждая программа выполняется в своём отдельном виртуальном адресном пространстве. Соответственно, программа ничего не знает о том, в каких физических адресах она находится. А все работы по преобразованию виртуальных адресов в физические берут на себя аппаратные средства компьютера. Как правило, код и данные процесса реально загружаются в физическую память небольшими кусками - страницами - когда они действительно нужны. Сама программа ничего об этих преобразованиях не знает. Это позволяет

- использовать в программе больше оперативной памяти, чем доступно на самом деле
- избежать фрагментации памяти, т.к. страницы имеют небольшой фиксированный размер и загружаются в свободной место
- экономно использовать оперативную память

Comment: Операционная система **не управляет** вируальной памятью, и **не занимается** преобразованием адресов - эти и множество других функций выполняет отдельное аппаратное решение(обычно встроенное в процессор/микроконтроллер) - контролер памяти(MMU)

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: По крайней мере в Linux программа может, используя /proc/self/pagemap узнать свои физические адреса

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, а таблицами страниц  MMU (да и управлением TLB) разве не ОС занимается? И если это не относится к **управлению виртуальной памятью**, то куда отнесете такие операции?

Comment: @КириллМалышев, у виртуальной памяти есть  еще одно крайне полезное для прикладных программ свойство -- очень длинные **непрерывные области**

Comment: @avp, управлением и обработкой занимается не ОС

Answer (score 0):

Физическая память это оперативная память, которая находится на ОЗУ. Когда она заканчивается, необходимо где-то хранить данные запущенных программ, поэтому на жёстком диске выделяется место под виртуальную память, которая выступает в роли оперативной памяти.

Заполнение участков памяти реализуется непосредственно ОС.