Что значит выделить память для процесса
Не могу понять, что значит выделить память для процесса. Прочитал много статей, но не могу уловить суть, что значит выделить виртуальную память процессу, и почему виртуальной памяти больше чем памяти на устройстве в общем.

Про отличие виртуальной и физической памяти: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928497

Для начала. Про таблицы для MMU, которые описывают виртуальную память, вы уже читали? Если да, то что именно не понятно?

Я просто не могу понять на фундаментальном уровне, зачем процессу, программе нужна память для его выполнения, не могу допереть на низком уровне, быть может есть какая-то аналогия для более простого понимая. Говорится в статьях, книгах, что процессу выделяется память для его выполнения или же выполняющаяся программа заняла в памяти столько-то столько-то места. Что хранится в этой выделенной памяти, я понял что хранятся адреса других элементов используемых в процессе , но не более.
